# workbox precacheAndRoute does not handle window.fetch or XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

When using workbox (5.1.3) and setting up the service-worker.js like

```
precacheAndRoute([
  {url: '/version.txt', revision: 'v1' },
]);
```

I can navigate in browser to `localhost://version.txt` and see inside chrome console that this content is fetched via caching from workbox.

Message in console shows:

```
workbox Precaching is responding to: /version.txt
```

But when trying to fetch the resource inside my javascript app via:

```
  window
    .fetch('/version.txt')
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response.text();
      } else {
        throw Error('no version');
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('content: ' + data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

the fetch command will try to read this content directly from network and skipping workbox Precaching. Also when simulating offline, I get an error for fetch instead the cached response.

Getting crazy ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging further into this issue - I found the problem (at least on my site)

Full working example:

#### /index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>My New Project!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Example Service Worker</h1>
  <p>A simple Test</>
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### /index.js

```
let registration;

var initServiceWorker = () => {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register('./sw.js')
      .then((reg) => registration = reg)
      .catch((error) => console.log('Registration failed with ' + error));
  }
}

var fetchTest = () => {
  console.log('VERSION FETCH Test looking for: /version.txt');
  window
    .fetch('/version.txt', { method: 'GET'})
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response.text();
      } else {
        throw Error('no version.txt file');
      }
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('AVILABLE VERSION FETCH: ' + String(data).trim());
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}

var xmlhttpTest = () => {
  console.log('VERSION XHR Test looking for: /version.txt');

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", '/version.txt', true);

  xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        console.log('AVILABLE VERSION XHR: ' + xhr.responseText);
      }
    }
  }

  // initialize request
  xhr.send(null);
}

console.log("JavaScript is amazing!");

initServiceWorker();

setTimeout(() => fetchTest(), 5000);

setTimeout(() => xmlhttpTest(), 10000);

setTimeout(() => { console.log('Registration update ...'); registration.update()}, 20000);

setTimeout(() => fetchTest(), 30000);

setTimeout(() => xmlhttpTest(), 35000);
```

#### /sw.js

```
// Sample service worker
const SW_VERSION = 'a2';

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  console.log('SW INSTALL: ' + SW_VERSION);
  skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  console.log('SW ACTIVATE: ' + SW_VERSION);
  skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
  console.log('WORKER (' + SW_VERSION + '): fetch event in progress ... ' + event.request.url);
  if (event.request.method !== 'GET') {
    console.log('WORKER: fetch event ignored.', event.request.method, event.request.url);
    return;
  }
});
```

#### /version.txt

```
v1.0.0
```

You may have a look into your console to see that also while using FETCH or XMLHTTREQUEST the fetch event from service worker will drop a message.

---

### And now about (my) issue:

If placing the javascript (/index.js) with fetch and xmlHttprequest in the same place (scope) as service-worker (/sw.js) **everything works as expected**

**BUT**

if leaving the javascript in a subfolder like (/js/index.js) **THIS WON'T TOUCH THE FETCH LISTENER** from service-worker (/sw.js) **ANYMORE** even if /js should be in scope???

Strange but happy to get that now ;-)

Comment: UPDATE: when adding header to nginx config and scope to service worker registration, I can also place the source file in /js sub-path and get it working. (e.g.: add_header 'Service-Worker-Allowed' '/';)

Comment: HINT: Also found somewhere else but to remember here again: When reloading page using SHIFT-RELOAD this will bypass/skip the registration of service-worker - just use reload!

Answer (score 0):

You want your service worker to intercept your navigation request and serve your file.

You should use the precaching mecanism from workbox

For example

```
new routing.registerRoute(new routing.NavigationRoute(
    new precaching.createHandlerBoundToURL('/version.txt'), {
        allowlist: [new RegExp('/version.txt')]
    }
))
```

Comment: Hi @pl4n3th, thanks for feedback. Its not working - whatever I try - :-( As I understand workbox - precacheAndRoute will invoke all necessary precaching and routing mechanism? Do you have any working code for simple precaching and workbox?